# Ubuntu 15.10 gnome edition won`t boot - error symbol 'grub_efi_secure_boot' not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, gnome, uefi

I have a problem with my ubuntu 15.10 gnome edition. If a link with pastebin from boot repair disk is all that's needed to come up with a fix, i won`t steal your time:

**Most recent pastebin:** http://paste.ubuntu.com/15849278

**Less recent pastebin:** http://paste.ubuntu.com/15849119

**Error:** symbol 'grub_efi_secure_boot' not found
**Dual boot:** Yes, with windows 10, which boots just fine.

**Fixes i`ve found and tried:**

update-grub,
reinstalling grub,
reinstalling the system,
using boot repair live cd

**If more elaboration is needed:**

Basically i've tried a lot of distro's recently. I've even tried the latest kubuntu, and it worked just fine. Gnome ubuntu (both 14.04 and 15.10) is where i've hit a rock. I've installed it once, it gave me the stated error. I've installed it again, same outcome. I`ve installed Manjaro lxqt, it worked just fine, installed ubuntu gnome, error again. If i use a live cd called 'super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.02s4' and boot ubuntu manually from there - it works.

I just wan't to add, that i rarely use terminal, so you can basically treat me like a beginner. And, as it is my first post here: Hello, sorry for any mistakes, i`m polish :)

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that either:

- You have some leftover GRUB files from a previous installation that are causing problems with the current one; or
- You've run into a bug in GRUB (or at least its current build)

If you're confident it's not the first issue, you might want to [file a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) about the problem.

As a practical matter, one possible solution is:

1. Boot with your workaround method.
2. Install my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as follows:

   1. Type `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind`
   2. Type `sudo apt-get update`
   3. Type `sudo apt-get install refind`
   4. When prompted, respond that you *do* want to install rEFInd to the EFI System Partition (ESP).
3. Reboot. rEFInd should come up as your default boot manager and you should be able to boot with it.
4. You may want to adjust the boot configuration. The single most popular change seems to be editing the boot entries, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#hiding)

If, after installing rEFInd, the system doesn't boot correctly, you should still be able to use your workaround method to boot. You can then adjust the boot order with `efibootmgr` to restore GRUB.

Comment: Fory for such a long delay, but the problem resolved itself :) After trying to install linux for like a 1000th time, on 1 am i've of course clicked the wrong thing and wiped my hard drive clean, along with all of my boot problems. I was about to do it anyway, if not in a slightly less brutal way (my windows 10 install was becoming REALLY bloaty), so that's fine. Maybe i`ll use your method another time, thanks for trying to help mate!